# Multipile grouping in regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have a string

```
s="<response>blabla  
   <head> blabla 
      <t> EXTRACT 1</t>  
      <t>EXTRACT 2</t>  
   </head>

   <body> blabla   
      <t>BODY 1</t>
      <t>BODY 2</t>
 </response>"
```

I need to extract the text betwen the tags  and  but only if its in the head part.
I tried

`regex="(?:<t>([\w.,_]*)*)</t>`

`re.findall(regex,s)`

but it is fetching the body part too , i understand that i need to tell it to stop at the closing head tag but I couldnt come up with any way

PS:The string is in a single line, I split it for better readability.And i want to do this using regex and not xml parsers.

Comment: if it is xml, consider xml libraries first. if you don't want use, please tell the reason.

Comment: no its in python and not  related to web in any way, its in sql and i need to read it from python

Comment: my question is not metioning web, why do you say not related to web? and what's the matter whether the string is from sql or not?

Comment: the head,body tags are other names, not sure if we an parse it using xml libraries, will try now And yes it doesnt matter if its from sql

Comment: Note that it is preferable to use an xml parser for tasks like this, if applicable. If you have to do it with an expression, you could use a lookahead to make sure you only get tags that precede the closing tag for the block you're interested in. For your example: `<t>(.*?)</t>(?=.*?</head>)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the header first :

```
s = "<response>blabla  <head> blabla <t> EXTRACT 1</t>  <t>EXTRACT 2</t>  </head> <body> blabla  <t>BODY 1</t> <t>BODY 2</t> </response>"
pattern_head = "<head>(.*)</head>" 
header = re.findall(pattern_head, s)
print(header)
```

This gives : `[' blabla <t> EXTRACT 1</t>  <t>EXTRACT 2</t>  ']`
Then get what you want from the head :

```
pattern = "<t>(.*?)</t>"
substring = re.findall(pattern,header[0])
print(substring)
```

`>>> [' EXTRACT 1', 'EXTRACT 2']`

Comment: yeah this will work

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from [@oriberu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11411342/oriberu)

`regex=<t>(\w+)</t>(?=.*?</head>)`